# unable to get ngtools/webpack to

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Trying to get AOT compiling in Angular 4 with ngtools/webpack, but whatever i try, it will not work. I have followed other tutorials but with no effect.

I keep getting this kinda error:

> rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.aot.js --progress
>   --profile --bail
>
> 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 activeModuleNotFoundError: Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/src/
>   app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\Bit
>   bucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\src'
>       at factoryCallback (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:260:39)
>       at factory (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:247:20)
>       at resolver (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:65:21)
>       at asyncLib.parallel.e (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:138:21)
>       at D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3824:9
>       at D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:460:16
>       at iteratorCallback (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1032:13)
>       at D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:944:16
>       at D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3821:13
>       at apply (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:21:25)
>       at D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:56:12
>       at resolvers.normal.resolve (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:130:23)
>       at onResolved (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:70:11)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at afterInnerCallback (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:138:10)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at Resolver.applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1 (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:181:46)
>       at innerCallback (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:125:19)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:283:15
>       at D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:38:4
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at afterInnerCallback (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:138:10)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at Resolver.applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1 (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:181:46)
>       at innerCallback (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:125:19)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:283:15
>       at innerCallback (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:123:11)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>   resolve './../$$_gendir/src/ app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\src'   using description
>   file: D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\package.json (relative
>   path: ./src)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file:
>   D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src)
>       using description file: D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\package.json (relative path:
>   ./$$_gendir/src/ app/app.module.ngfactory)
>         as directory
>           D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\$$_gendir\src\ app\app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\$$_gendir\src\ app\app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\$$_gendir\src\ app\app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
>         .ts
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\$$_gendir\src\ app\app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
>         .html
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           D:\Bitbucket\egbolig\Frontend\Application\$$_gendir\src\ app\app.module.ngfactory.html doesn't exist
>         .css

package.json

```
{
  "name": "eg-bolig",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.aot.js --progress --profile --bail"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",

    "primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.3",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.28.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.24.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.26.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.39.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^0.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^0.23.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^0.12.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^0.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^0.20.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^0.15.5",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.5.1",

    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",


    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",

    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.2",

    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5"
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.html', '.css', '.scss']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // {
            //     test: /\.ts$/,
            //     use: [
            //         {
            //             loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            //         }, 'angular2-template-loader']
            // },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=assets/fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=assets/fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=assets/fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=assets/fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
                        { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
                        { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
                        { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                use: [
                    { loader: "to-string-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } }, // todo: checkup, Doesnt support sourcemap yet (its in merge)
                    { loader: "css-loader", options: { sourceMap: true }},
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
                    { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, outputStyle: 'expanded' } },

                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                use: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            favicon: "src/assets/img/favicon.ico"
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: '/angular/',
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
          mangle: {
              keep_fnames: true
          }
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': {
              'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
          }
      }),
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
          htmlLoader: {
              minimize: false // workaround for ng2
          }
      })
    ]
});
```

webpack.aot.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var prodConfig = require('./webpack.prod.js');
var AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(prodConfig, {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: '@ngtools/webpack'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),
            entryModule: helpers.root('src',' app', 'app.module#AppModule')
        })
    ]
});
```